# Box model within table-cell display type

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

This problem is about the behaviour of the box model within a table-cell display type, particularly in Google Chrome. I've experimented with it for a while, but still don't understand what's happening. Here is a minimal working example of my problem:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.table {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

.content {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

(You can also use [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/390wxpg4/1/).)

In Firefox and Internet Explorer, the *cell* fills the whole page, the *containers* border equals the page boundaries, and the *content* is positioned symmetrically within. In Chrome the *cell* still fills the whole page, and the *content* is still positioned symmetrically within the *container*. However, the *containers* bottom border is positioned above the page bottom (by twice its padding).

For me this looks as if Chrome applies the vertical padding twice, but the second time only at the bottom. This only happens with border-box box-sizing.

**Question**: Can you explain this behaviour and the difference between FF/IE and Chrome?

Comment: There's no CSS justtification for that. It's a Chrome bug.

Comment: Are you sure? If so, is this a "known bug" in Chrome or Blink? (Today I was able to reproduce this on Opera and Android browser 4.4 as well.)

Comment: Possibly this one: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=285744